# Can I publish if I develop a tool, but it solve non important problem only? (Mathematics)

Tags: publications, research-process, mathematics

My research is in mathematics.

I have developed an interesting quantity X. Combined with other quantity Y, I can solve a certain problem.

However,

1. I don't know if the problem itself is important or not.
2. It needs to combined with other tools to work.

Can I still publish my idea?

Comment: As you've described it your result could be worth a fields medal (e.g. Cohen's method of forcing) or be of essentially no interest to anyone. I think you need to discuss this with someone whose work is related to your work and provide some specifics.

Comment: 'I don't know if the problem itself is important or not.'  Is that "After an extensive literature search, I've found no sources commenting on whether the problem is important or not", or "I'm new to the (sub-)field and therefore don't know whether the problem is important or not"?

Comment: @DanielHatton It is the latter case, I am a student and my supervisor doesn't work on that field, so I don't know what to do.

Comment: @Ken.Wong OK - well, a good start would be to change it from the second case to the first case, i.e. carry out a thorough literature search to find out whether anyone thinks the "certain problem" is important and why (and also to find out whether anyone else has already developed quantity X or anything closely-related to it, or any alternative way of solving the "certain problem").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether you can publish your current work or not depends on the publisher. But you can certainly write it up and submit it to an appropriate journal. At that point it will get reviewed by people with more experience than you have and you will get the feedback that you need.

The Mathematical Association of America (MAA) publishes a [student focused journal](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/college-mathematics-journal/the-college-mathematics-journal) that might be an appropriate place for your work.

I'd suggest that you get your advisor to review your paper before submission. You may get valuable feedback even if it isn't their main focus.

The reviewers might, of course, decide that your work is trivial and not worth publishing. But they might also notice connections that you don't. In any case, the process of writing it up formally is probably worth the effort.

Comment: Normally, the *College Mathematics Journal* does not publish original research.  It is a "student focused journal" in the sense that (hopefully) students are able to read it.

Comment: @GEdgar, thanks. Perhaps you can suggest a good journal to the OP. I vaguely remember from long ago that there was a journal for student work.

Comment: Rose-Hulman Undergraduate Mathematics Journal ; Involve: A Journal of Mathematics ; Minnesota Journal of Undergraduate Mathematics ; SIAM Undergraduate Research Online ; also see https://uncw.edu/honors/info/student-life/journals-that-publish-undergraduate-student-research.html

Answer (score 2):

Based on your reply to @DanielHatton's comment, you may have some research to make in that subfield to know about uses of the tool you discovered. Make your research in the subfield your tool may apply to and talk to people.

- If you find something: great, you now have an application for your tool
- If you don't find anything: it doesn't mean your tool doesn't have any application, let me explain.

In my humble opinion, publishing findings which may seem to have no clear application at the moment could still be useful years down the line. There are examples in history where research work had no application for a long time before..it did (*anyone having such an example in mind is welcome to edit*).

(Unfortunately?) not all papers are ground breaking. Yours probably won't be (as the vast majority of papers), but it might, sooner or later.

So I would encourage you to write a paper about it. You also mentioned that you are a student and I think that practising paper writing is valuable for students. You'll have some experience in case you want to become an academic, and if you don't, papers always look good on a resume.